# Zip and merge the string

Tags: python

'''
return a new string containing the 2 strings interwoven or zipped together.
ex:
Input:
'hi'
'ha'
Ouput:
hhia

Input:
'lzr','iad'
output:
lizard

```
def interleave(str1, str2):
    ls1 = zip(str1, str2)
    print(list(ls1))
    # prints [('h', 'h'), ('i', 'a')] as expected
    ls2 = [''.join(x) for x in ls1]
    print(ls2)
    # prints below. not as expected
    # output: []
    print(list(ls2))
    # prints empty list. not as expected.
    # output: []
    # Below prints hhia correctly
    ms1 = ''.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(str1,str2))
    print(ms1)
    # Output: hhia

interleave('hi','ha')
```

its working when i give in a single line (ms1).
when i split and give its not working (ls1, ls2).
Can anyone advise the root cause?
'''

Comment: Your last statement is an assignment, not a value... What happens if you just put `s2` oh a line by itself at the end?

Comment: Please research about the problem a little bit, before making a question for it here.As @EdwardPeters stated you are doing an assingment in the repl, put `s2` on a newline to see it's value

Comment: To be fair this is a google-resistant problem - there's no immediately obvious keyword to search on, and the assignment thing isn't necessarily obvious (or the case in all languages). They also clearly played around trying to fix it, as they have a working version. I don't think it's a bad question.

Comment: It's working fine. I don't know how you got that output. In the future, please make a [mre] before asking a question, to isolate the problem. And welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which has tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: code updated fully now. Hope this makes everyone clear on the issue,

Comment: @ChidambaramP That's totally different code. In the future, please ask a new question instead of changing what you're asking. This is now a duplicate of this existing question: [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](/q/25336726/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea.. this question is related to zip function. since its an iterator related.. doesnt a duplicate to the existing question. understand before u comment.

Answer (score 2):

Because `zip()` is a **python iterator**. Once you retrieve the values of `ls1` in third line(`print(list(ls1))`), the `ls1` become empty.

Try this case, it would be more clear:

```
def interleave(str1, str2):
    ls1 = zip(str1, str2)
    print(list(ls1))  # prints [('h', 'h'), ('i', 'a')] as expected
    print(list(ls1))  # empty
    ls1 = zip(str1, str2)
    print(list(ls1))  # prints [('h', 'h'), ('i', 'a')] as expected



interleave('hi','ha')
```